# What is the best way to represent 2D data with an attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

Assuming I have an excel file with the following structure:

| Year | Type A | Type B | Type C | Type A | Type A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | London | Paris | Lisbon | Spain | Berlin |
| 2010 | 70 | 72 | 81 | 84 | 42 |
| 2011 | 20 | 32 | 31 | 82 | 92 |
| 2012 | 50 | 42 | 21 | 39 | 22 |
| 2013 | 72 | 12 | 51 | 82 | 52 |

What would be the best way to represent this using Pandas or Xarray, while being able to:

- Get all cities of Type A (or any other Type) and plot the years
- Plot all the cities regardless of their type

I thought about reordering the table, using the cities as the columns, but how would I set each cities type as some sort of metadata, since it's not really the data I want represented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first wrangle the data into this form.

| Year | Type | City | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | A | London | 70 |
| 2010 | A | Spain | 84 |
| 2010 | A | Berlin | 42 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

To get all cities of Type A (or any other Type) and plot the years:

```
df[df.Type == 'A'][['Year', 'City', 'Value']]
```

To get all the cities regardless of their type:

```
df[['Year', 'City', 'Value']]
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long. That would require having a lot of duplicate entries, wouldn't it? 4 rows per city.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, I think we cannot escape having to store the information somewhere. If one city can have many Type, then i think this is a good way to store it for simple (in terms of coding) retrieval. 

But if one city can only have 1 type eg.London can only be Type A, then denormalizing the table into 2 would save some disk space: one for ['Year', 'City', 'Value'], the other one for ['City' , 'Type']. And the second one ['City', 'Type'] can be a python dict instead of a table. But the retrieval code will then have to call and read from the dict.